# Verifying whether a decimal value is a valid

Tags: ruby, string, validation

I want to verify the numbers after a given decimal. Values above 10 should be considered as invalid. I would need a regex command to verify. For example:

Input: Expected response

1. `0.005`: valid
2. `1.003`: not valid
3. `1.04`: valid

I tried the following regex, but it doesn't give me the expected result.

```
/\d{0,1}\d{0,3}/
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How is `1.003` invalid? Its below 10.

Comment: also what's the input string? just the numbers?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Regex is not a command.

Comment: Sorry. I would need a regex expression. the values from 0.001 to 0.999(Increments of 0.001) are valid and 1.00 to 10(Increments of 0.01) is valid. the input string would just be numbers (Eg:1.05 )

Comment: Then why is 1.003 not valid?

Comment: After 1 the decimals should have only two places

Comment: Now that is something we could not have guessed. Add all these conditions in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly

```
^(0\.\d{3}|[1-9]\.\d{2}|10\.00)$
```

[online test](http://rubular.com/r/cvbwd5ySBx)